# HTML: Align progress bars vertically

Tags: html, css, django

I have a list of items with a progress bar each: 
[image]

What I want is that all progress bars are aligned, no matter how long the text on the left is. (I already know how long the longest text on the left will be)
The code snippet (in Django):

```
<strong style="font-family:Arial">{{ score.0 }}</strong>
<progress value="{{ score.1 }}" max="10" style="margin-left: 5%"></progress>
```

`style="margin-left: 5%"` doesn't work because it's relative to the corresponding text. I already tried using "vertical-align" variations, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are using `flex`:

```css
section {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

strong, progress {
  flex-basis: 50%
}
```

```html
<section>
  <strong>text</strong>
  <progress value="1" max="10"></progress>
  <br>
  <strong>longer text</strong>
  <progress value="1" max="10"></progress>
  <br>
  <strong>even longer text</strong>
  <progress value="1" max="10"></progress>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends how to you want to approach it, one way would be to give all the texts the same length via css, for example:

```
<strong style="width:200px;">text goes here</strong>
<progress></progress>
```

The other way, would be to have both the `<strong>` and the  `<progress>` inside a container, a wrapper of sorts, and then give that container some flex rules to make both elements go to the opposite ends, like this:

```
<div class="container">
<strong>text</strong>
<progress></progress>
</div><!-- .container -->

and for the css

.container {
display:flex;
width:100%;
flex-direction:row;
justify-content:space-between;
align-items:center;
}

strong {width:200px;} // or 50%;
progress (width:200px;} //or 50% or whatever you need
```

Comment: I tried both solutions, but none of these changed the alignment of the progress bars

Comment: it depends on how you're wrapping them, seeing the contextual code would help

Answer (score 0):

Can be achieved by 2 lines of CSS.

And, given below is a sample HTML structure FYR.

```css
strong{
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<strong style="font-family:Arial">Text</strong>
<progress value="3" max="10" style="margin-left: 5%"></progress>
<strong style="font-family:Arial">Longer Text</strong>
<progress value="3" max="10" style="margin-left: 5%"></progress>
<strong style="font-family:Arial">Even Longer Text</strong>
<progress value="3" max="10" style="margin-left: 5%"></progress>
```